# Billy Bibbit's age in One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest?

Tags: character, one-flew-over-the-cuckoos-nest

Sure we all know Billy Bibbit from 1975's *One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest* was young, but what about something more specific? How old was Billy in this movie?

Comment: I don't think that is mentioned anywhere in movie.

Comment: The new tag would be over 25 chars. I tried to abbreviate it sticking to the suggestions from Napoleon Wilson's answer http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/1016/whats-the-policy-on-abbreviating-titles-of-movies-tv-shows/1027#1027, but couldn't think of anything good. cuckoos-nest, one-flew-cuckoos-nest, one-flew-over-cuckoos-n - either one seems wrong.

Comment: @Hegemon - The only problem is, people will start typing "one-flew ..." for the tag (if there will ever be another question) and not "one-over-...". While I see the dilemma, this tag is not going to work, IHMO.

Comment: @Paulster2 This tag has been added by Napoleon Wilson. I didn't add any, because I couldn't find anything satisfactory.

Comment: In the book, he's supposed to early 30's, though seems much younger.

Comment: @Hegemon - Sorry, didn't realize. I assumed it was you due to what you had said. The new tag is much better.

Comment: @Paulster2 No problem. And I agree that the new tag is better.

Answer (score 2):

I am pulling this information from a couple of different sources:

First - Billy is stated to be 4 years younger than McMurphy in this [Cliff Notes](http://www.cliffsnotes.com/literature/o/one-flew-over-the-cuckoos-nest/character-analysis/billy-bibbit) link.

Second - Randle McMurphy's age at time of death (Smothered by the Chief) was 38. Birth/death given as April 22, 1925 – December 11, 1963, according to [the wiki for the character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randle_McMurphy).

That would put Billy's age at 34, which fits with the rest of the information in the story.